# Selecting multiple dataframe columns by position in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, select, indices

I have a (large) dataframe.  How can I select specific columns by position?  e.g. columns 1..3, 5, 6

Rather than just drop column4, I am trying to do it in this way because there are a ton of rows in my dataset and I want to select by position:

```
 df=df[df.columns[0:2,4:5]]
```

but that gives `IndexError: too many indices for array`

DF input

```
 Col1     Col2     Col3       Col4        Col5       Col6
 1        apple    tomato     pear        banana     banana
 1        apple    grape      nan         banana     banana
 1        apple    nan        banana      banana     banana
 1        apple    tomato     banana      banana     banana
 1        apple    tomato     banana      banana     banana
 1        apple    tomato     banana      banana     banana
 1        avacado  tomato     banana      banana     banana
 1        toast    tomato     banana      banana     banana
 1        grape    tomato     egg         banana     banana
```

DF output - desired

```
 Col1     Col2     Col3       Col5       Col6
 1        apple    tomato     banana     banana
 1        apple    grape      banana     banana
 1        apple    nan        banana     banana
 1        apple    tomato     banana     banana
 1        apple    tomato     banana     banana
 1        apple    tomato     banana     banana     
 1        avacado  tomato     banana     banana     
 1        toast    tomato     banana     banana     
 1        grape    tomato     banana     banana
```

Comment: @djk47463: that question uses a list of names, this one uses a list of indices. I retitled both questions to make the slight difference clear.

Comment: @smci The accepted answer in the linked question uses positions, not labels

Comment: @smci, that’s not really true, the question was broken into two parts, 1 is by column indexes, the second by label. Most of the answers here are highly correlated with the answers there...

Comment: @djk47463: well then the question's confused, we could delete the first half without losing anything. What should we do? Let me try to edit it for clarity.

Answer (score 17):

What you need is numpy [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html)

```
df.iloc[:,np.r_[0:2,4:5]]
Out[265]: 
   Col1     Col2    Col5
0     1    apple  banana
1     1    apple  banana
2     1    apple  banana
3     1    apple  banana
4     1    apple  banana
5     1    apple  banana
6     1  avacado  banana
7     1    toast  banana
8     1    grape  banana
```

Comment: learn a new trick :P

Answer (score 7):

You can select columns 0, 1, 4 in this way:

```
df.iloc[:, [0, 1, 4]]
```

You can read more about this in [Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).

> • iloc is primarily integer position based (from 0 to length-1 of the
>   axis), but may also be used with a boolean array. .iloc will raise
>   IndexError if a requested indexer is out-of-bounds, except slice
>   indexers which allow out-of-bounds indexing. (this conforms with
>   python/numpy slice semantics). Allowed inputs are:
>
> ◦ An integer e.g. 5
>
> ◦ A list or array of integers [4, 3, 0]
>
> ◦ A slice object with ints 1:7
>
> ◦ A boolean array
>
> ◦ A callable function with one argument (the calling Series, DataFrame
>   or Panel) and that returns valid output for indexing (one of the
>   above)

Comment: @jp_data_anlaysis how do I select range of columns though?

Comment: a few ways: for columns 1 to 5, you can use `1:6`, for 1 to 5 and 7 to 10, you can create a list: `list(range(1, 6)) + list(range(7, 11))`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `range` with `concatenate` from `numpy` and get columns where `np.concatenate` is used to combine two different ranges:

```
import numpy as np
df = df[df.columns[np.concatenate([range(0,3),range(4,6)])]]
df
```

Output:

```
   Col1     Col2    Col3    Col5    Col6
0     1    apple  tomato  banana  banana
1     1    apple   grape  banana  banana
2     1    apple     NaN  banana  banana
3     1    apple  tomato  banana  banana
4     1    apple  tomato  banana  banana
5     1    apple  tomato  banana  banana
6     1  avacado  tomato  banana  banana
7     1    toast  tomato  banana  banana
8     1    grape  tomato  banana  banana
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the pandas iloc method:

```
df_filtered = df.iloc[:, [1,2,3,5,6]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The error OP face is from `df.columns[0:2,4:5]` where too many indices were put into. IIUC, you can put all the column names you need together to do a selection.

```
from itertools import chain
cols_to_select = list(v for v in chain(df.columns[0:2], df.columns[4:5]))
df_filtered = df[cols_to_select]
```

If there can be name conflicts in cols_to_select, do selection using `iloc` as jp_data_analysis suggested or `np.r_` as Wen suggested.

Comment: Aha, this is good :-)